# Jersey 1.9 - How to get path param name and corresponding value

Tags: jersey, aop, guice, jersey-1.0

I need your help figuring out how to intercept a Jersey 1.9 RS call and modify a query param on a match with path param.

Let's say I have a RS class:

```
@Path("/bookstore")
public class BookStore {

  @GET
  @Path("/books/{bookName}")
  public Book addBook(@PathParam("bookName") String bookName, @QueryParam("isLegacy") String isLegacy) {
      return book;
  }
}
```

I want to intercept this RS call and get the `bookName` from the path or query parameters. If the bookName is say "Spiderman" then I want to modify the request's query param `isLegacy` to false.

The example is obviously all made up.

Is their a way for me to do this via Filter, AOP or any similar mechanism? I am using Guice, Jersey 1.9.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that extends `PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider` and annotate it with `@Provider`. By overriding `getInjectable` method, you can tell Jersey to modify query parameters as you described above.